# String.slice and string.substring

Tags: javascript, substring

I am brand new at programming, especially JS. I seem to be stuck on a split string.

I need to split a string into two separate strings. I know I can do so with the slice and substr like below, which is my sample I have of what I know. I am assuming my name is Paul Johnson. with below I know that if I have an output of first and last name with the parameters I setup, I will have Paul as my first name and Johnson as my second.

```
           var str = document.getElementById("fullName").value;

           var firstname = str.slice(0, 4);
           var lastname = str.substr(4, 13);
```

My question is that I am getting hung up on how to find the space and splitting it from there in order to have a clean cut and the same for the end.
Are there any good resources that clearly define how I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're asking how to split a string on a space character?

Comment: maybe devdocs.io is a nice place to search functions and theri meanings http://devdocs.io/javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
    var str = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    var space = str.indexOf(" ");
    var firstname = str.slice(0, space);
    var lastname = str.substr(space);

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

What you're after is String split. It will let you split on spaces.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var str = "John Smith";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

Will return an Array with ['John','Smith']

Comment: I tried this previously, but I did not want the "," to occur. I want the names to be in their own 'placeholder' for first name and last name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split()`.

The syntax of split is: `string.split(separator,limit)`

`split()` returns a list of strings.

The split() function defaults to splitting by whitespace with to limit.

**Example:**

```
var str = "Your Name";
var pieces = str.split();
var firstName = pieces[0];
var lastName = pieces[1];
```

`pieces` will be equal to `['Your', 'Name']`.

`firstName` will be equal to `'Your'`.

`lastName` will be equal to `'Name'`.

Comment: I tried this previously, but I did not want the "," to occur. I want the names to be in their own 'placeholder' for first name and last name.

Answer (score 1):

str.indexOf(' ') will return the first space

Comment: i would actually caution against that because it can return -1 and screw up the proceeding slice() command...

Answer (score 1):

There is a string split() method in Javascript, and you can split on the space in any two-word name like so:

```
var splitName = str.split(" ");
var firstName = splitName[0];
var lastName = splitName[1];
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: I tried split, but it came back [object HTMLSpanElement]. Not sure what I did incorrectly.                                                      var str = document.getElementById("fullName").value;       
            var splitName = str.split(" ");
            var firstName = splitName[0];
            var lastName = splitName[1];

Answer (score 1):

A good way to parse strings that are space separated is as follows:

```
pieces = string.split(' ')
```

Pieces will then contain an array of all the different strings. Check out the following example:

```
string_to_parse = 'this,is,a,comma,separated,list';
strings = string_to_parse.split(',');
alert(strings[3]); // makes an alert box containing the string "comma"
```